# How to create module which can surpass authentication in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have complete angular js working  application.But i have a challenge ahead in that single page has to be made which will open on click of link.

Now the challenge for me is that if user is not logged in(Session not created) and someone trying to access any link it will redirect to login page,but in current case since i dont want user to be logged in and directly taken to that page and let him perform actions.

One simple solution for me was to create different application but i want to utilize the contents and code of current application.

Any one has faced any situation like this before,If yes then is there any possible way?

Comment: Modify the code that performs the redirect to the login page to have an exemption for this single page.

Comment: @pratswinz , try to keep the session related function in a method and use `resolve` in the `routing` to check the autentication